# Flutter Theme Changing dark to light using onpress event

Tags: flutter, dart, themes

I am working with flutter projects
and I want to change the themecolor using an `onpressed` event

I tried some code but not working.

**main.dart file**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Screens/HomePage.dart';

void main()=>  runApp(MyApp());

ThemeData _lightTheme = ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.light,
  primaryColor: Colors.white,
);
ThemeData _darkTheme = ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.light,
  primaryColor: Colors.white,
);
bool _ktheme = true;

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Wallbay',
      theme: _ktheme ? _lightTheme : _darkTheme,
      home: MyHomePage('Alpha Papers'),
    );
  }
}
```

**HomePage.dart file**

```
........
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.brightness_medium_outlined),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _ktheme = !ktheme;
          });
        },
      )
......
```

Comment: You can't just say "doesn't work".  What does it do, and how is that different from your expectations, and what have yoouo tried when you're fixing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your theme objects `_lightTheme` & `_darkTheme` are the same objects with different names.

They both have `brightness` set to `Brightness.light` & `primaryColor` as `Colors.white`.

```
ThemeData _lightTheme = ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.light, // <----
  primaryColor: Colors.white, // <----
);
ThemeData _darkTheme = ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.light, // <--- Dark mode having light brightness
  primaryColor: Colors.white, // <---- Dark mode having white color
);
```

Change these to the following:

```
ThemeData _lightTheme = ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.light, // light mode
  primaryColor: Colors.white,
);
ThemeData _darkTheme = ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.dark, // dark mode
  primaryColor: Colors.black,
);
```

Also, your `onPressed` code looks wrong.

```
setState(() {
  _ktheme = !_ktheme; // Notice: I renamed ktheme to _ktheme
});
```

Comment: Thank you. But My Second Question is How to save this _ktheme variable on shared prefrences.

Comment: Send me the question link & I will answer it there.

Comment: [codepen](https://codepen.io/klakshmanan/pen/yLaXRNE)